# IntelliJ formatting group declarations like in Eclipse, but across empty lines

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA 15. The formatter option "Wrapping and Braces->Group Declarations" has two options, which align field declarations like this correctly:

```
private static final String _StringOne    = "Test";
private static final String _StringLonger = "Foo";
```

However, Eclipse seems to do this much more "correctly" when these two declarations are separated by a empty line. If I have this code:

```
private static final String _StringOne    = "Test";

private static final String _StringLonger = "Foo";
```

Eclipse will format it just like that, the equal signs line up even across empty lines as well.

However, IntelliJ will format it like this:

```
private static final String _StringOne = "Test";

private static final String _StringLonger = "Foo";
```

Which quickly (in my opinion) gets ugly, especially when field names are of different length. There's many times where I visually group variables together or want newlines in between javadocs, etc etc.

I've searched high and low, but can't seem to find if I can make IntelliJ format "group declarations" across empty newlines. Is there a way? Or maybe some IntelliJ plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found no way available in IntelliJ. If you like how `Eclipse` formats (other settings as well), I would try to take the Formatter file from your `Eclipse` and import it in your `IntelliJ`. Here it explains how to do it: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/01/intellij-idea-13-importing-code-formatter-settings-from-eclipse/

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but for that particular "feature" it seems to ignore whatever Eclipse does to make that particular formatting happen. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it appears there's no way to do this out-of-the-box. However, installing the Eclipse Code Formatter plugin did the trick: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546